# Javascript Efficiency with Constants passed as Parameters?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, constants

I have a general JavaScript question. I'll give you my scenario and then ask you the question.

**Scenario**

I am making a table with (currently) *over 3000 rows*, and it is growing by 5-10 every day. I am using a javascript plugin to style this table and add useful functionality. It currently takes 15 seconds to fully load the page, after which everything runs smoothly (sorting, paging, etc.). That is a very slow initial load, though. The plugin offers a way with less DOM parsing, where you pass it an array of the information to be placed inside the table, which I am very intrigued by. However, I want to make this as fast as possible, because there will still be an array of 3000 rows (each with 11 columns of, on average, 10 characters).

**Question**

Would it be significantly faster to use a JavaScript *const* to store this giant array? Specifically, does JavaScript know not to put a *const* on the stack when passed as a parameter?

Furthermore, is this simply too much for JavaScript to handle? Should I dismiss this idea and start with AJAX now (which would mean much slower functionality but much faster pageload)?

Thanks!

Comment: If it were my site, I'd use AJAX to avoid roundtripping so much data.

Comment: 1) What is a "javascript plugin"? 2) If you're dealing with the DOM, it is no longer a question of "is this too much for JavaScript to handle?" but rather "is this too much for a browser's implementation of the DOM to handle?". 3) I like air quotes.

Comment: here is what i'm thinking of using: `http://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html`

Comment: @Roatin: the javascript array would be used internally and DOM objects only created as needed, so even 100 rows at a time would be fast (much faster than 3000+ initial then narrowing it back down to 100)

Comment: Note that "const" doesn't even work in all browsers, particularly IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you say interaction is fast once the page is loaded I guess your biggest bottleneck is transfering the data over the wire.

I would send everything as **JSON** (compressed with **[gzip](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip)**) which is very **lightweight** and **fast** to load.

I think styling should be done with CSS not JS. Also if you want the best UX **initialize** your table with **less** (1-200 elements), and then deal with the rest. It is better for the user if you show something right at the beginning.

Storing the array can't be a problem because [GC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29) will clear it up.

Comment: i just tried implementing using the giant JS array, and cut the pageload from 15 seconds to 6 seconds, but that still isn't fast enough. i'm going to use AJAX and JSON now. thanks =)